# replace all to "hello" except string that is in between double quotes

Tags: regex, shell, sed

```
$ cat file1
"rome" newyork
"rome"
rome
```

What do I need to fill in the blank?

```
$ sed ____________________ file1
```

I want output like

```
"rome" newyork
"rome"
hello
```

if my input is like this

```
$ cat file1
/temp/hello/ram  
hello   
/hello/temp/ram
```

if I want to change the hello that does not have slashes what should I do? (change hello to happy)

```
temp/hello/ram 
happy  
/hello/temp/ram
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed 's/[^\"]rome[^\"]/hello/g' your_file
```

tested below:

```
> cat temp
    "rome" newyork
    "rome"
    rome 

> sed 's/[^\"]rome[^\"]/hello/g' temp
    "rome" newyork
    "rome"
   hello

>
```

Comment: Thaknks. I am looking for this :)

Comment: if input is like this " /temp/hello/ram   hello       /hello/temp/ram " if I want to change the hello that does nt have slashes what should I do ???  Sample  O/P : temp/hello/ram   happy   /hello/temp/ram   [change hello to happy].

Answer (score 0):

Why is `rome` changed to `hello` but `newyork` is not? If I'm reading the question correctly, you're trying to replace everything not in double quotes with `hello`?

Depending on the exact use cases you want (what happens to the input string `""`?), you probably want something like this:

```
sed 's/\".*\"/hello/'
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont see a direct way to replace all others except those enclosed inside " "

However, with recursive sed, a brute force method, you can achieve it.

`cat file1 | sed "s/\"rome\"/\"italy\"/g" | sed "s/rome/hello/g" | sed "s/\"italy\"/\"rome\"/g"`

Comment: However, I would love to see a simple command with one sed, if any.

Answer (score 0):

The second problem can be solved with a simple perl one-liner (assuming only one hello per line):

```
perl -pe 'next if /\//; s/hello/happy/;'
```

The first problem requires some internal book keeping to keep track of whether you are inside a string or not. This can also be solved with perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;

my $state_outside_string = 0;
my $state_inside_string  = 1;

my $state = $state_outside_string;

while (my $line = <>) {
    my @chars = split(//,$line);
    my $not_yet_printed = "";
    foreach my $char (@chars) {
        if ($char eq '"') {
            if ($state == $state_outside_string) {
                $state = $state_inside_string;
                $not_yet_printed =~ s/rome/hello/;
                print $not_yet_printed;
                $not_yet_printed = "";
            } else {
                $state = $state_outside_string;
            }
            print $char;
            next;
        }
        if ($state == $state_inside_string) {
            print $char;
        } else {
            $not_yet_printed .= $char;
        }
    }
    $not_yet_printed =~ s/rome/hello/;
    print $not_yet_printed;
}
```